# keras with tensorflow : a CUDA runtime call was likely performed without using a StreamExecutor context

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using kears with tensorflow backend, and following is the problem. Is there any can solve this problem, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Paste the messages in text instead of image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Theano: Initialisation of device gpu failed! Reason=CNMEM\_STATUS\_OUT\_OF\_MEMORY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099918/theano-initialisation-of-device-gpu-failed-reason-cnmem-status-out-of-memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by a illegal value of CNMEM. According to theano [doc](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html#config.config.lib.cnmem), CNMEM can only be assigned as a float.

> 0: not enabled.
>
> 0 < N <= 1: use this fraction of the total GPU memory (clipped to .95 for driver memory).
>
> 1: use this number in megabytes (MB) of memory.

You can also refer to [here](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/4302).

The warning is due to a change in Theano (Kera's backend). It will change from CUDA to GpuArray. You can refer to [here](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Converting-to-the-new-gpu-back-end%28gpuarray%29) for a solution.

Actually if you fix the warning, the error will disappear as well according to:

> This value allocates GPU memory ONLY when using (CUDA backend) and has no effect when the GPU backend is (GpuArray Backend). For the new backend, please see config.gpuarray.preallocate